# Screen -dmS working from command line but not from Java (Spigot restart script)

Tags: java, shell, minecraft, gnu-screen

I recently changed my dedicated server and since then the script I use to restart my minecraft server isn't working anymore. 
I can call the script using `sh start.sh` and my server starts, however when I use the in-game /restart command or when I instruct the server to restart from my plugin, the server closes and never restarts.

Here is the content of my start.sh

`screen -dmS mc_hub1 java -jar -Xmx2048M -DIReallyKnowWhatIAmDoingISwear server.jar`

Unless I'm running the script from the command-line, nothing happens, the screen isn't even created.

The issue seems to be originating from `screen -dmS mc_hub1` because the restart instruction works if I remove it, actually it feels like I can't use anything related to screens from Java but it used to work so I'm a bit lost.

The dedicated server on which everything works is running Debian 9.9, Screen 4.05.00 and the new one is running Debian 9.11 and Screen 4.05.00.

- I tried to add the -L option to enable logging but it doesn't even create the file,
- Everything in the folder has read and execute permissions,
- I tried to call the script from my plugin using `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`, no exception but still no result

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("start.sh");
                    pb.directory(new File("/home/minecraft/uhc/"));
                    pb.start();
```

- Java version doesn't seem to be causing the problem (I tested with the latest one and the one from my first dedicated server which is older)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Would you consider using your OS vendor's process supervision mechanism instead of mucking around with `screen` at all? (On most Linux distros, that means the Right Thing is a systemd service these days).

Comment: ...`screen` is designed to make a fake/virtual  "terminal" that can be detached from, reattached to, etc. When you run as a subprocess of a JVM, there's typically no terminal at all in the first place. Not to say it can't still be made to work in those circumstances, but it's still being put to use well outside its design goals.